# Как сделать так чтобы если юзер ввел в input() занчение которое не было предусмотрено в if код не закрывался а вызывал input() снова

Tags: python, input

если что то не правильно сформулировал сорри, только начинаю изучать python

Comment: Используйте бесконечный цикл

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое это использовать цикл while:

```
answers = {'test': 'value', 'hello': 'some value'}
while True:
    query = input()
    if query in answers:
        break
```

answers - содержит варианты правльных ответов.

Как только пользователь введёт нужное значение, цикл прервётся и выполнение программы продолжится.

Comment: Пожалуй `while query not in answers`  будет лучше